# How to use async methods with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, async-await

I am working on a **.net core (2.2) web application** and have a controller which is responsible to have an **on-demand data sync processing**. For the same, I have kept a button on click of which a call to an async method of a service is triggered.

Internally, this service call processed below actions

1. Fetches data from database for data sync process
2. Split data into batches for batch mode of data sync processing
3. Prepare data model for relevant batch data
4. Sent prepared data batch to targeted message queue

For interaction with database from within service, **Db-context object was provided using IOC / Dependency Injection i.e. via Constructor**.

In order to identify the issue cause, I make service method calls using numerous ways :

- Calling Async Method with Task.Run()
- Calling Async Method without Task.Run()
- Calling Sync Method with Task.Run()
- Calling Async Method with ConfigWait(true)

In all cases, it resulted into no change, still getting the **ObjectDisposedException for DbContext object**.

> On understanding the scope system of IOC more, it seems to me that
>   scope is getting disposed for db-context object once the response is
>   provided back to user.

**Code snippet** with minimal lines is represented below :

***AzureSearchIndexController.cs***

```
public class AzureSearchIndexController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult StartIndex()
   {
      _azureSearchDataSyncService.StartIndexingAsync(_siteId, _siteName);
   }
}
```

***AzureSearchDataSyncService.cs***

```
public class AzureSearchDataSyncService : IAzureSearchDataSyncService
{
   public AzureSearchDataSyncService(JobContext context,
            ICacheHandler<AzureSearchDataSyncModel> cacheHandler,
            AzureJobsTopicBus azureJobsTopicBus)
   {
      _context = context;
      _cacheHandler = cacheHandler;
      _azureJobsTopicBus = azureJobsTopicBus;
      azureSearchDataSyncModel = new AzureSearchDataSyncModel();
   }

   public async Task StartIndexingAsync(int siteId, string siteName)
   {
      try
      {
         int fetchedData = 0;
         int _batchSize = 10;
         List<AzureJobMessageModel> azureJobMessages = new List<AzureJobMessageModel>();

         var jobsToAdd_Update= GetData(siteId);
         while (dataSyncModel.SyncStatus && 
            fetchedData < jobsToAdd_Update.Count)
         {
            var batchData = jobsToAdd_Update.Skip(fetchedData)
                          .Take(_batchSize - azureJobMessages.Count)
                          .ToList();
            if (batchData.Count <= 0)
               continue;

            azureJobMessages.AddRange( 
               PrepareAzureJobMessageModel( 
                      PrepareAzureSearchIndexerModel(batchData), 
                  EntityActionEnum.updated)
            );

            fetchedData += batchData.Count();

            if (azureJobMessages.Count >= _batchSize)
            {
               //Method sending batch data
               await _azureJobsTopicBus.SendMessageAsync(azureJobMessages);
               dataSyncModel.ProcessedData += azureJobMessages.Count();
               dataSyncModel.ProcessedBatches += 1;
               azureJobMessages = new List<AzureJobMessageModel>();
            }
         }
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          throw ex;
      }
   }
}
```

**Desired Result :** Want to have an async mode of data sync process on button click.

**Actual Result :**

> getting error "ObjectDisposedException - Cannot access Disposed Object
>   (Db-context)"

. Do anyone have any idea on this?

**Note:-** I don't want to make action method async. I will be using this method calls either in service methods or CRUD actions which includes CRUD operation logic. I want data sync logic to run in background without affecting the response time for CRUD actions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the service call is not being awaited the response is completing before the service, which will dispose of the context. Causing the error when the service tries to access the context.

Make the action async and then await the service

```
public class AzureSearchIndexController : Controller {

    //...

   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> StartIndex() {

        //...

        await _azureSearchDataSyncService.StartIndexingAsync(_siteId, _siteName);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is true but I can't apply this for my case as this data sync method call need to be implemented for CRUD operation actions as well.

Can you suggest any other mechanism using which this can be feasible as I can't make my action async as per current project structure

Comment: @rakeshgirase what do you mean. how does making it async not allow crud?

Comment: As described earlier as well, my action method were created with primary objective to perform CRUD operation. And for each crud operation action, I want this process to run in separate thread as a background process individual from my action logic.

When I make the action async, it response back when both my action logic as well as my data sync logic gets completed. I don't want it to wait for data sync process completion.

Comment: @rakeshgirase That's possible to do, but the consequence is that the caller will not know if the operation succeeded or failed. Do you know how you would handle a failure?

Comment: As of now, we haven't considered the failure case, but planned to manage using ILogger or text file to track data sync activity logs

Comment: Sounds like you need a queue and a worker that processes that queue. There are various ways to implement those.

Comment: Right now the data sync content is sent to azure service bus only (queue), but using an async method call. @juunas, can you brief me more on worker

Comment: @rakeshgirase Take a look at [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)