# C# Dependencies injected into service all disposed in async methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

C# ASP.NET gives me this error when trying to run a dependency in my service:

> CG10.Bot.DiscordSender[0]
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at CG10.Bot.DiscordSender.SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command) in E:\SERVER\CG10Website\Bot\DiscordSender.cs:line 261

The dependency works in the "initialize" function I made (not shown) just fine, which is a regular method and not async. The async methods do not work whatsoever, whether its my SQL Database or the IServiceManager (my attempt to fix problem). Note that the async methods are all run by an eventhandler (specifically from the discord.net package) and not called by any of my code.

Program file: How it's created

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDiscordSender, DiscordSender>();
```

Injection into Service:

```
public DiscordSender(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IUnitOfWork db,
            TFDbContext tfdb,
            ILogger<DiscordSender> logger, ILogger<SlashCommand> loggerOther, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IServiceProvider service)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _db = db;
            _tfdb = tfdb;
            _logger = logger;
            _loggerOther = loggerOther;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
            _service = service;
        }
```

async function that doesn't work:

```
public async Task SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command)
        {
            try
            {
                _db = _service.GetService<IUnitOfWork>(); //This here crashes, goes to "Catch" block very far at the bottom (not shown)
                if (_db == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogCritical("Failed to receive IUnitOfWork service");
                    return;
                }
            //More code beyond this, but its omitted.
```

I've really dug through forums, but all of them say to change the return of the `async` method to `Task` instead of Void (which mine already is). I'm honestly lost on what to do to fix this unfortunately. I expect it to just work.

Comment: Closest thing to this problem (which I think IS the problem) is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748496/how-to-use-async-methods-with-dependency-injection
It's gotta be the reason why, but I don't know how to get past this too

Comment: Given you've withheld so much code for anyone to reproduce this, but given the error, I'm going to speculate you're trying to call `SlashCommandHandler` outside of a request context.  Provide more information on how this is wired up, in particular how `SlashCommandHandler` gets called and how that caller (or chain of callers) is registered in your DI context.

Comment: @possum Ah, sorry about that. Discord.net calls the SlashCommandHandler function through a Func<SocketSlashCommand, Task> callback. I subcribed it to the event by using _client.SlashCommandExecuted += SlashCommandHandler;

When someone runs a command on discord, it calls the function SlashCommandHandler asyncronously.

Also, the thing calling it (discord.net) isn't connected to DI context whatsoever. It's a completely different package outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. First, I added the scope as a singleton instead of scoped, so

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDiscordSender, DiscordSender>();
```

Then, I also injected "IServiceScopeFactory" into DiscordSender. Lastly, I used

```
using (var scope = _service.CreateScope())
            {
                var _db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
```

to get the Service (since a singleton cannot have scoped services inside it).
_service is the IServiceScopeFactory dependency I injected.

Used this page primarily: [Cannot consume scoped service 'MyDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618406/cannot-consume-scoped-service-mydbcontext-from-singleton-microsoft-aspnetcore)